# Remove folder with non-ASCII filenames with PHP on windows machine

Tags: php, windows, unlink, rmdir

I Would like to remove a directory from a windows OS using PHP. I have written a recursive function to find all files in the directory, and normally this works.

However, in one of the directories, there is a file with japanese characters in its name. When using `scandir()` it shows up as ???????????????.mp4 and using `unlink` on that direct output of scandir produces an error of "file not fount".

So: How to remove a directoy which contains files with japanese (or other non-ASCII) characters in its name?

- Is it even possible to do this with PHP (any version...) under Windows?
- Is there a way to remove the directory w/o deleting the files first?

Thank you!

Comment: Good luck. Hopefully PHP uses the wide versions of Windows C API functions.

Comment: It does, starting with PHP 7.1. Any filename charset is supported if default_charset=utf-8 set, otherwise it'll narrow to the old behavior. Thanks.